# Does "the weed" refer to tobacco or marijuana?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In *The American Pageant* by Thomas A. Bailey, the writer is using "weed" to rephrase "tobacco":

> By 1612 he had perfected methods of raising and curing the pungent
>   **weed**, eliminating much of the bitter tang. ... Virginia’s prosperity
>   was finally built on tobacco smoke. This “bewitching **weed**” played a
>   vital role in putting the colony on firm economic foundations.

According to Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English

> [the weed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-weed)
>   *informal* cigarettes or tobacco

But "weed" nowadays is also closely associated with marijuana. If I am using "**the** weed" in my own writing, would native speakers take it to mean "tobacco"?

Comment: "Weed", in the context of something smoked or otherwise consumed, would almost certainly be taken to mean marijuana or some similar herb, absent further explanation.

Comment: That would  depend largely on context.

Comment: Tolkien repeatedly describes hobbits puffing away on their *pipe-weed*. In 1937 it would have been understood as tobacco (or equivalent), but the modern interpretation of *weed* adds a whole new dimension to the Ring tales.

Comment: [A recent contributor to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Help_desk/Archives/2019_May_4#List_of_films_containing_frequent_marijuana_use) is convinced that the use of the word "weed" in the film of LOTR must mean Marijuana. Nobody else in the discussion agreed with them.

Comment: Take into count that "bewitching" might just be nothing other than _addictive_ in today's terms. And tobacco is much more addictive than marijuana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As is noted in the question, the Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English defines **[the weed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-weed)** as:

> *informal* cigarettes or tobacco

However, the same dictionary defines **[weed](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/weed)** (*without* the article) as:

> 6. [uncountable] cannabis

So it would appear that there's a clear distinction between the count and non-count usages.

The question goes on to ask:

> But "weed" nowadays is also closely associated with marijuana. If I am using "the weed" in my own writing, would native speakers take it to mean "tobacco"?

It will depend both on context and whether it's being used correctly. Most people are likely to distinguish between

> I'm trying to give up the weed

and

> I'm trying to give up weed.

But a sentence like "have you got the weed?" could be ambiguous without a suitable context.

Answer (score 2):

There is an article [**here**](https://slate.com/human-interest/2014/03/the-etymology-of-marijuana-and-the-rise-of-weed-as-the-preferred-slang-term-for-cannabis-sativa.html) which discusses when the term *weed* began to be used as a slang term for marijuana and concludes that it was in the 1930s. Although it further claims that this name didn't become popular until the 1990s.
The word *marijuana* entered the English language in the late 19th century  both according to the above article and [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marijuana_(word)).
On the other hand the name *cannabis* dates back to the 16th century according to [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymology_of_cannabis).
I am prepared to accept that *weed* as applied to tobacco dates from the early 17 century.
Just how and why the old name for tobacco got applied to marijuana is unclear.

Comment: Cop:  What you got there???  Kid on street:  Just some weed.